# ClassCastException:cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.f

Tags: java, apache-spark

`rdd.flatmap()` create many task

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.f of type scala.Function3 in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MappartitionRDD
```

Serialized lambda  can not deserialize